# Css not applied in accordion in angular2

Tags: angular

I have installed accordion from [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion).

It working fine but I can't overwrite its CSS.

```
.card-block {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
 }
 a:focus {
  background: transparent;
  text-decoration: none!important;
 }
a:hover{
  background: transparent;
   text-decoration: none!important;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try `!important` keyword?

Comment: This could seem obvious, but are you adding the stylesheets in the right order to your index.html? Remember your desired styles should be applied in the last place.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of accordian code.

Comment: The best thing you can do right now is to debug your app with chrome dev tools, firebug or something similar. Check your accordion element for which styling is applied.

Comment: @Stefan default bootstrap style is applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more specification in angular2, you have to use `/deep/` before your css class

```
/deep/.card-block {
 text-align: left;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
/deep/a:focus {
background: transparent;
text-decoration: none!important;
}
/deep/a:hover{
background: transparent;
text-decoration: none!important;
}
```